# group_concat question (mysql)

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have some trouble of figuring out how to use group_concat to produce certain output.

Here is what I have: 2 tables:

1st contains clients' information,

2nd contains animals' information for
   each client.

I have to produce this output:(i omitted the boundaries, but basically this is one column of the table)

```
Client: 25 Harris, Eddie
Animals: Koshka(cat),Gutsy(snake),Edger(snake),Fritz(cat),George(turtle),Big Mike(turtle)
```

This is what I've tried :

```
select  group_concat ( distinct 
        'Client: ', CL.cl_id, space(1), 
        CL.cl_name_last,', ', 
        CL.cl_name_first,'\n',
        'Animals: ', AN.an_name, '(', 
        ifnull(AN.an_type, 'No Animals'), ')', '\n') as 'Client Info'
from p_vets.vt_clients CL 
join p_vets.vt_animals AN using (cl_id) 
group by CL.cl_id;
```

I get the following output (small part from the table):

```
Client: 25 Harris, Eddie
Animals: Koshka(cat)
,Client: 25 Harris, Eddie
Animals: Gutsy(snake)
,Client: 25 Harris, Eddie
Animals: Edger(snake)
,Client: 25 Harris, Eddie
Animals: Fritz(cat)
,Client: 25 Harris, Eddie
Animals: George(turtle)
,Client: 25 Harris, Eddie
Animals: Big Mike(turtle)
```

I don't understand how to group the animals to be displayed under each client they belong to.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group_concat should only include the animals part.

Try this:

```
select  concat(
          'Client: ', CL.cl_id, space(1), CL.cl_name_last,', ', CL.cl_name_first,'\n',
          'Animals: ', group_concat(
            concat( AN.an_name,'(',coalesce(AN.an_type, 'No Animals'),')')
          )
        )
from p_vets.vt_clients CL 
join p_vets.vt_animals AN using (cl_id) 
group by cl_id;
```

Comment: Thank you! :) One more question, if I left join the tables and one of the clients will show up without animals would `coalesce(AN.an_type, 'No Animals')` still work? It gives me just plain 'NULL' for all entries without animals.

Comment: @notrockstar Wrap the `GROUP_CONCAT` with another `COALESCE()`.

Comment: The coalesce where it is now seems bit off -- it catches the case where an animal has a name but no type.  To catch the case where there are no animals, you need a coalesce outside of the group_concat.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, @awm Thank you. I never came across that function.

Comment: @notrockstar Ur welcome, If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green check-mark nexto the answer.